# 'While' loop count is worng?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, iteration

```
ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
print(ans)
```

should return 19 but mine is returning 12?

Here is what I have:

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    rushes = 0
    current_height = 0
    rush_height_counter = 0
    back_sliding_counter = 0
    rush_height_gain = 0.95 ** rush_height_counter * rush_height_gain
    back_sliding = 0.95 ** back_sliding_counter * back_sliding

    while current_height < slope_height:
        current_height = current_height + rush_height_gain
        rushes += 1
        rush_height_counter += 1
        back_sliding_counter += 1

        if current_height < slope_height:
            current_height = current_height - back_sliding

        else:
            return rushes
```

Answer (score 2):

with this piece of code `0.95 ** rush_height_counter * rush_height_gain` do you mean

```
0.95 ** (rush_height_counter * rush_height_gain)
```

or

```
(0.95 ** rush_height_counter) * rush_height_gain
```

I think you want the first one but python ( as I know ) do second one!